# Run same attributes in parent classes using child class

Tags: python, pandas, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have following classes:

```
Class A:
  def __init__(self,df,metrics=True,data=True):
    ..
    ..
    self.preprocess(df)

  def preprocess(self,df):
    ..
    ..
    return(df)
  def train(self,df):
    .. 
    ..
    return(df)

  def fit(self,df):
    .. 
    ..
    return(df)

Class B:
  def __init__(self,df2):
    ..
    ..
    self.preprocess(df2)

  def preprocess(self,df2):
    ..
    ..
    return(df2)

  def train(self,df2):
    .. 
    ..
    return(df2)

  def fit(self,df2):
    .. 
    ..
    return(df2)
```

I want to construct a Class C, which takes in both parent Class A and B:

```
Class C (A,B):
   def combine():
     ..
     ..
     return()
```

The class A and B are two machine learning models giving some result using different algorithms. I want to use Class C to wrap these classes (A and B) and then combine their result into one.

The problem I am facing is that these two classes A and B have same attributes (but take in different dataframes). Now when I am calling `C.fit()`, its giving me error, cz I think due to the fact only fit for Class A is being called as it was written earlier.

I want to know if there is a way I can call similar attributes for A and B (A takesin df and B takes in df2) using C and in the end combine these results?

**In short what I want is: When I call `C.fit()`, I want both `fit()` to run in A and B and also, create self.variables in both these classes which would have been created when called individually.**

Comment: Just don't use inheritance use composition and be done with it.

Comment: If the 2 ancestors have methods with the same name, only the ones from the parent that comes first in the *MRO* will be available in the derived class (instance). Name the methods differently in the ancestors, but that would be just ugly. Multiple inheritance is not the way to go here.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. Will probably change the names

Comment: If A and B do the same thing but on different data why not make them once class that accepts data as an argument to init??

Comment: @WoodyPride can you please elaborate? I am actually very new to class objects.

Comment: @KshitijYadav no, don't rename the methods. **Just don't use inheritance**. Use composition.

Comment: Yes, I did that now. Thanks